# Can we use google's direction API?

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I have referred all question of stackoverflow but i don't found exact answer of what I want. Can we use google's direction api for drawing route ? Here in sense of does it create any problem in application submission. Will Use of this api violate any rules of google or apple that may cause application rejection ?

Comment: I am still not sure if Apple will reject the app over MKMapview? Are you been clear? I have same question as you. i.e., I have used MKMapview but using Google Directions API. Please help so I can go further to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We looked into this for a project last year. Short summary:

If you use the Google Maps API, as provided by Apple, you are *not allowed* to do any kind of route-finding / mapping. This is part of the license that Google gave to Apple, and Apple gave to you. If Apple notices you doing this, they will probably reject you (they don't want to get sued by Google).

However, if you use Google Maps *without* Apple's code (i.e. do not use UIMapView etc), and instead go direect to Google, you may get a different license. In that case, you should be accepted - it's not longer Apple's problem, so they're happy.

(off the top of my head, the license you get direct from Google still bans using route finding)

If you embed a UIWebView, and do the route-finding directly on a Google-provided webpage, that's fine.

(but: read the license agreements carefully. The Apple/Google license is in the SDK documentation, and the Google license is easy to find on the web, just google for it)

Comment: Thanks for reply any libarary or any other way to do that.

Comment: OpenStreetMap will let you do pretty much anything, free - BUT you'd have to build the route-finding logic yourself, on top of their low-level data. There's a bunch of commercial companies out there that will sell you licenses to do this stuff, but usually it's very expensive. This is a high-value product; if you need it "free", you're probably stuck with Google and webpages

Comment: As google published his Direction API, i'm not sure the licence has not changed. Is this still the case?

Comment: I've seen a LOT of apps that now use Apple's maps, and then simultaneously open a web connection to the Google webservers, and use Google-web (without displaying it) to do the route-finding, then draw it over the top of Apple maps. This WAS - as far as I know - forbidden under the original licenses, but there are literally hundreds of iPhone apps doing it, so I guess the licenses have changed, or else Google and Apple don't care any more

Comment: @Adam, I am still not sure if Apple will reject the app over MKMapview? I have same question. i.e., I have used MKMapview but using Google Directions API for getting directions and drawing route. Please help so I can go further to use.

Comment: My answer was from 5 years ago. I doubt the license today is the same. Why don't you read the current license and check for yourself?